# How do I load new data into a div?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, post

I've got a review section on my website. 
In the center of the page are all the reviews retrieved from the database.

On this same page you can write a new review.
The point is to write a review and submit it.
If the review is submitted it should load with ajax above my other reviews.

The js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function() {
            var restaurant = $('#restaurant').rateit('value');
            var service = $('#service').rateit('value');
            var food = $('#food').rateit('value');
            var name = $('#name').val();
            var description = $('#desc').val();
            var dataString = 'name='+name+'&description='+description+'&restaurant='+restaurant+'&food='+food+'&service='+service;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "reviewprocess.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    $('#blee').load()
                            .hide()
                            .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                            });
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
});
```

The review section:

```
<ble id="blee">
    <?php
        $query = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM reviews");
        while($review=$query->fetch_object()){
    ?>
    <div class="section2_box">
        <header>
            <b><?php echo $review->name ?></b><br><hr>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Restaurant </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="rateit" data-rateit-value="<?php echo $review->restaurant ?>" data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-readonly="true">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bediening </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="rateit" data-rateit-value="<?php echo $review->service ?>" data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-readonly="true">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Eten </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="rateit" data-rateit-value="<?php echo $review->food ?>" data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-readonly="true">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table><hr>
            <p><?php echo $review->description ?></p>
        </header>
    </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?></ble>
```

The form:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="comment">
            <b>Geef beoordeling!</b><br><hr>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Restaurant</td>
                    <td><div class="rateit" id="restaurant"></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bediening</td>
                    <td><div class="rateit" id="service"></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Eten</td>
                    <td><div class="rateit" id="food"></div></td>
                </tr>
            </table><hr>
                Naam: <br><input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
                Omschrijving: <br><textarea name="description" id="desc" cols="30" rows="4"></textarea>
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Beoordeel!" class="bl" id="submit">
            </form>
```

Reviewprocess.php:

```
include('connect.php');
$name = $_POST['name'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$service = $_POST['service'];
$food = $_POST['food'];
$restaurant = $_POST['restaurant'];

$sql->query("INSERT INTO reviews (restaurant, service, food, name, description) VALUES      ('$restaurant', '$service', '$food', '$name', '$description')");
```

After submitting the form the data succesfully stores in the database.

My problem is that the new review don't show in '#blee' untill I refresh the page.
How do I get the new review to appear in '#blee'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var restaurant = $('#restaurant').rateit('value');
        var service = $('#service').rateit('value');
        var food = $('#food').rateit('value');
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var description = $('#desc').val();
        var dataString = 'name='+name+'&description='+description+'&restaurant='+restaurant+'&food='+food+'&service='+service;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "reviewprocess.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {
                $('#blee').empty()  
                $('#blee').append()
                        .hide()
                        .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                        });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Add this in your code for "reviewprocess.php"

```
include('connect.php');
$name = $_POST['name'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$service = $_POST['service'];
$food = $_POST['food'];
$restaurant = $_POST['restaurant'];

$sql->query("INSERT INTO reviews (restaurant, service, food, name, description) VALUES        ('$restaurant', '$service', '$food', '$name', '$description')");

   $query = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM reviews");
    while($review=$query->fetch_object()){

  $returnData .= ' <div class="section2_box">
    <header>
        <b> echo $review->name</b><br><hr>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Restaurant </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="rateit" data-rateit-value=" $review->restaurant" data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-readonly="true">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bediening </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="rateit" data-rateit-value=" $review->service " data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-readonly="true">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Eten </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="rateit" data-rateit-value=" $review->food " data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-readonly="true">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table><hr>
        <p> $review->description </p>
    </header>
</div>
    }';

 echo $returnData;
```

Comment: If I try your solution '#blee' just disappears. The data is still inserted in the database.

Comment: Ah i see. Just try the code i add above in your  "reviewprocess.php"

Comment: It appears again, but still without the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
success: function() {
    var obj = '
        <div class="section2_box">
            <b>'+name+'</b><br><hr>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Restaurant </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="rateit" data-rateit-value="'+restaurant+'" data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-readonly="true">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bediening </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="rateit" data-rateit-value="'+service+'" data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-readonly="true">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Eten </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="rateit" data-rateit-value="'+food+'" data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-readonly="true">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table><hr>
        <p>'+description+'</p>
        </div>
    ';
    $('#blee').append(obj);
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work, using this method it wont even execute reviewprocess.php for some reason.

Comment: It might not seem to work, but it is EXACtLY what you need to do. Since everything is working fine (process, etc) all you need to do in the success function is "append" or "prepend" in the "#blee" div. I'd personnaly prepend. If you want to add effect, you can do this: var container = $('<div />'); container.append(obj); container.hide(); $('#blee').prepend(container); container.fadeIn();

Comment: put the error function, and log it... Like this: error: function(error){ console.log(error); } and observe the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can load data directly from a `php` file

```
$('#blee').load('reviewprocess.php');
```

Additionally you can send variables in load:

```
$('#blee').load("reviewprocess.php?"+dataString);
```

You can show `#blee` on this way:

```
$('#blee').load('reviewprocess.php',function(){$('#blee').fadeIn(300);});
//It will show #blee after load() fn, of course you have to apply css display none before load()
//I think, only this last line will work for you
```

Comment: And then I should place the data retrieval in reviewprocess.php?

Comment: You can place your table in reviewprocess.php, I don't know how to get vars from load(), also you can check $.post or $.ajax with post methods using json to get vars. My method is for send data and get tables or messages from a php file.